# Read each line from a file into its own different 2D array

Tags: java, file, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

I wanted to read from a file in Java. The complication is to manage it into its own 2D array.
The file is line the following:

```
#  1  1    1  2    1  3    1  4    1  5    2  3      8   8      9   7    18  17 
*  2  4    2  5    2  6    2  7    2  8    18  18    10  11     16  18 
HRow 5 5 20 3
VRow 6 6 10 4
```

The spaces are the delimiter between the pairs. 2 spaces within the pairs and 3 spaces between the pairs.

The output should be:

```
private static final int[][] HASH_LOCATIONS = {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2, 3}, {8, 8}, {9, 7}, {17, 18}};
private static final int[][] AST_LOCATIONS = {{2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {18, 18}, {10, 11}, {16, 18}};
private static final int [][] H_ROW = {{5,5,20,3}};
private static final int [][] V_ROW = {{6,6,10,4}};
```

I have tried the following:

```
       try {
            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileIn);
        while (scanner.hasNext()){
            String itemType = scanner.next();
            if (itemType.equals("#")) {
                ArrayList<Integer> hashLocations = new ArrayList<>();
                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    hashLocations.add(scanner.nextInt());
                }
            } else if (itemType.equals("*")) {
                ArrayList<Integer> astLocations = new ArrayList<>();
                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    astLocations.add(scanner.nextInt());
                }
            } else if (itemType.equals("HRow")) {
                ArrayList<Integer> hLocations = new ArrayList<>();
                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    hLocations.add(scanner.nextInt());
                }
            } else if (itemType.equals("VRow")) {
                ArrayList<Integer> vLocations = new ArrayList<>();
                while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    vLocations.add(scanner.nextInt());
                }
            }
        }
            return true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return false;
        }
```

I am not sure how to manage this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would read line by line instead of char by char. For each line, if you know the amount of pairs (e.g: numbers expected) I would count them to ensure they are ok.

If the file has those definitions in front of the pairs (e.g: #, *, etc) Then I will ensure they are put in the right "bucket". I will use a map for this, so it allows for the addition of new value quite easily. But if you want to restrict to these only and blow up if anything else then this can also be achieved.

Also note, some of your spaces in the input file are potentially wrong, unless your definition is wrong, so please check it.

See below for some sample to get you started. This is based on the attached sample input (which is nothing else than yours except following the rule for spacing)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int EMPTY_COUNT_BETWEEN_TUPLES = 2; // after split
    List<String> allowedRowTypes = Arrays.asList("*", "#", "HRow", "VRow");
    Map<String, List<List<Integer>>> buckets = new HashMap<>();


    BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\e048222\\Playground\\stackoverflowPlay\\src\\com\\company\\input.txt"));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

            if(tokens.length == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid line");
            }
            String rowType = tokens[0];
            if(!allowedRowTypes.contains(rowType)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid line type");
            }
            List<Integer> tuple = null;
            int countEmpty = 0;
            List<List<Integer>> bucketValues = buckets.get(rowType);
            for(int tokenCount=1; tokenCount<tokens.length; tokenCount++) {
                String value = tokens[tokenCount];
                if(value.isEmpty()) {
                    countEmpty++;
                } else {
                    if(countEmpty == EMPTY_COUNT_BETWEEN_TUPLES) {
                        bucketValues = addToBucket(tuple, bucketValues);
                        tuple = null;
                    }

                    if(tuple==null) {
                        tuple = new ArrayList<>();
                    }

                    tuple.add(Integer.parseInt(value));
                    countEmpty = 0;
                }
            }
            bucketValues = addToBucket(tuple, bucketValues);
            buckets.put(rowType, bucketValues);
            System.out.println(bucketValues);

            line = reader.readLine();
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println(buckets);
}

private static List<List<Integer>> addToBucket(List<Integer> tuple, List<List<Integer>> bucketValues) {
    if (bucketValues == null) {
        bucketValues = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    bucketValues.add(tuple);
    return bucketValues;
}
```

Updated input file:

```
# 1  1   1  2   1  3   1  4   1  5   2  3   8  8   9  7   18  17
* 2  4   2  5   2  6   2  7   2  8   18  18   10  11   16  18
HRow 5  5  20  3
VRow 6  6  10  4
```

Output:

```
# 1  1   1  2   1  3   1  4   1  5   2  3   8  8   9  7   18  17
[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [8, 8], [9, 7], [18, 17]]
* 2  4   2  5   2  6   2  7   2  8   18  18   10  11   16  18
[[2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [18, 18], [10, 11], [16, 18]]
HRow 5  5  20  3
[[5, 5, 20, 3]]
VRow 6  6  10  4
[[6, 6, 10, 4]]
{#=[[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [8, 8], [9, 7], [18, 17]], HRow=[[5, 5, 20, 3]], *=[[2, 4], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [2, 8], [18, 18], [10, 11], [16, 18]], VRow=[[6, 6, 10, 4]]}
```

Not the cleanest code, but something to get your creative juices flowing. This will fail for pretty much any structure change of the input file, but allows for a lot of improvements.

Comment: Thanks for this. It surely helps. Will update asap.